# ubuntu 14.04 headphones not even recognize by alsamixer

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones

I've tried many ways to solve this problem and none of them seem to work for me:

I've tried modifying this file following another topic:

```
cd /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/
sudo cp analog-output-headphones.conf analog-output-headphones.bak
sudo nano analog-output-headphones.conf
```

and I've changed the [Element Headphone] switch to "on" and the volume to "merge".

Besides, when I use "alsamixer" it looks like my headphones are not recognized, but in my sound settings I have a digital output and a analog output.

I can also send my alsa-info file if necessary.

I'm attaching a screen shot of both my alsamixer and my sound settings.

I would appreciate any help in this matter, I know there are similar questions but, as I said, none of the seem to work for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you turn off automute in alsamixer

Comment: I finally couldn't attach  screenshot of my alsamixer (because of my reputation score...). I went one by one increasing the volume and pressing 'M' to turn off mute, so they should not be muted. The problem though is that the headphones are not even recognized in alsamixer